# how to use execlp() with redirected output

Tags: c, unix

i tried to write c program in Unix environment that using execlp function.

the command is:

```
 execlp("tsort","tsort","text.txt",">","1.txt",(char *)NULL);
 syserr("execlp");
```

i am  always gets the same error.
the error is:

```
tsort: extra operand `>'
```

what did i do wrong?

Comment: Don't include ">" or  "1.txt", they are instructions to the shell to redirect STDOUT to "1.txt"... you need to do that in your program before calling execlp.

Comment: Or just invoke shell; `"sh", "-c", ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'>' is not a parameter, it is normally interpreted by a shell. If you want to achieve the same effect in C code, you have to do the same thing the shell normally does:

1. open a file (`1.txt`) for writing
2. `fork()` a new process
3. [in child] replace the stdout of the new process with the file's descriptor using `dup2()`
4. [in child] exec the command

Simplified example code for POSIX:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200101L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int outfd = open("1.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (!outfd)
    {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        close(outfd);
        perror("fork");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (pid)
    {
        // child code
        dup2(outfd, 1); // replace stdout
        close(outfd);

        // just a "useless cat" for simplicity:
        execlp("cat", "cat", "redir.c", 0);
    }
    else
    {
        // parent code
        close(outfd);
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        if (WIFEXITED(status)) return WEXITSTATUS(status);
        else return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

As per the comment: If you don't mind replacing your process with the called program, you don't even need to fork and the program becomes very short:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200101L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int outfd = open("1.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (!outfd)
    {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    dup2(outfd, 1); // replace stdout
    close(outfd);
    execlp("cat", "cat", "redir.c", 0);
}
```

This of course is **not** what an *interactive* shell does.

Comment: The fork() isn't necessary for the redirect. Given that the OP was calling `execlp`, either they know how to use `fork` or they don't care about replacing the program image, or both. Really, all that is necessary is an open, a dup2 and a close, or alternatively a close and an open.

Comment: @rici actually correct, yes ... maybe I was thinking to much along the lines of a "shell". But OTOH, I really don't see the point *without* a fork ;)

Comment: It has its uses. Suppose you were doing a command processor. The last command in the list is kind of like a tail call. (Or, more precisely, it is a tail call.) Since all you're going to do is to resend its status code, you might as well do a "goto" (i.e. a direct exec) rather than fork+exec+wait+return. (Also true of boolean sequence: a && b && c: by the time you get to c, if you do, there's no point forking again.

Comment: @rici of course, but it's a very special case. After all, these are *example programs* and normally, you wouldn't just "forward" the child's exit code. BTW, why do you write a `close()` was necessary? it's necessary if you open the file and then `fork()`, but without a `fork()`, I don't see a reason for a `close()`.

Comment: If you do `fd=open(sth); dup2(fd, 1); execlp(...);` then `fd` is still open in the new image. That's only a bit untidy in the common case, but it might have undesirable consequences in uncommon cases. (You could set close-on-exec, of course).

Comment: Ok, hard to imagine a case ... maybe if the exec'd program detaches itself and unwillingly keeps an fd to the file ... just for the sake of being tidy, I'll add this to my examples, too.

Comment: Oh, and by the way. It *is* what bash does, in some cases. For example, if you do `bash -c command` and command is a simple command, it will just replace itself without forking. (Verify that by looking at pids if you don't believe me :) )

Comment: and for that comment, let's say *interactive* shell ... wow, lots of corners to explore for answering a seemingly simple question ;)

Comment: @YonatanAmir YW. So did you solve your problem? In case you didn't know yet, you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer. This has the immediate effect of giving the author some reputation (and also a little yourself), but what's important is that the answer is marked as the solution for future readers. Of course, there's no obligation to do so and you should only accept answers that actually solved your problem.